# "Not carrying cash" implication in a context

Tags: phrase-meaning

Currently reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/nearly-four-decades-tip-helps-141404272.html), there is a line,

> Virginia Hannon’s family has long wondered whether her killing might have been connected to a $380,000 inheritance she had collected from an aunt. Hannon had told friends about the money but had never flaunted it, Richard Hannon said.

> “People knew that she had gotten an inheritance from her aunt, **but she wasn’t the type of person who would carry cash, and she wasn’t out buying filet mignons,**” he said. “She drove an old car, and she was a very thrifty person.”

I guess that "she wasn't out buying filet mignons" connotes as the continuing sentence says that she was a thrifty person, but I'm wondering what would "not carrying cash" imply?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In context I understand this to mean she would not "carry *large amounts* of cash".  So although she was wealthy, she only carried a "normal" amount of money in her purse: perhaps tens of dollars, not thousands of dollars. If she needed to pay for a valuable item she would use a check (these remain common in the USA).

Similarly "filet mignon" is the most expensive cut of beef (in the UK it is about £50/kg). It is something that most people could only afford for special occasions.

Together they suggest a person who did not publicly appear to be wealthy.

Comment: Thanks. You had made an answer before I solved myself lol. By the way, "in the UK it is about £50/kg" That's far cheaper than here in Japan. For fillet mignon, I bet here it would cost 150£/kg, just FYI.